# Changing the look of new Gnome 3 title bars in with a GTK3 theme

Tags: gtk, themes, gnome, gtk3, gnome-3

I have a GTK3/Metacity theme which uses dark title bars.

Recent versions of Gnome 3 combine title- and toolbars, e.g. in Nautilus. I want to change their color to be consistent with all other GTK windows.

[image]

What is the attribute I need to look for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source code for the GTK+ themes is located in the https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-themes-standard/ git repository. The styling for the different widgets for Adwaita is located in the `themes/Adwaita/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css` file -- see the section starting:

```
/***************
 * Header bars *
 ***************/
```

Specifically:

- `.header-bar { ... }`
- `.header-bar:backdrop { ... }`
- `.header-bar .button.text-button { ... }`
- `.header-bar .button.image-button { ... }`

Comment: `.header-bar` along with `.header-bar .toolbar` did it. Thanks!

Comment: I can't find these css selectors in my theme, and adding them doesn't do much. Which Field do I need to change in the gnome tweak tool, btw?

Comment: Also, when I install a theme, it only changes the title bar background color for some of my apps. gVim and Firefox for instance stay grey.

Comment: @Costa The local installed version is a compiled binary -- you can edit the `gtk.css` or `gtk-dark.css` files there, adding the styles below. Or just look in the git repository I referenced. Firefox and gVim are using Gtk+ 2, so may not get styled with the Gtk+ 3 theme. Also, the menu bar would be `.menubar` and the toolbars `.toolbar` for Gtk+ 3 applications that use them and preserve the menu-toolbar UI model.

Comment: I'm lost, I've put more detail, and my real goal here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900779/how-can-i-change-the-title-bar-of-a-gnome-theme-to-black

Answer (score 0):

Although not 100% sure, I thought Nautilus is a GTK2 application.
If that is the case, you need to create a GTK2 theme next to your GTK3 theme.

You can put these folders next to each other.

Take a look in your /usr/share/themes folder for examples.

Does this help you?

Comment: Nautilus is the GNOME file manager: naturally it's kept up to date and does not use an obsolete GTK+ version. Typically nautilus depends on a fairly recent version, currently 3.9.11.

Answer (score 0):

You could install gtk-tweak-tool and configure your system to global-dark-theme.