# How can I change the title bar of a gnome theme to black

Tags: ubuntu, themes, gnome, gnome-shell

**Update:**

I tried changing the top line in my gtkrc2.0 file to this `gtk-color-scheme = "base_color:#000000\nfg_color:#000000\ntooltip_fg_color:#000000\nselected_bg_color:#000000\nselected_fg_color:#000000\ntext_color:#000000\nbg_color:#000000\ntooltip_bg_color:#000000"`
 but that didn't seem to help either.

I'm making some tweaks to my desktop (Ubuntu 14.04 with Gnome-shell 3.9.90) and I want to get my title bar black. By title bar I mean the thing you double click on to maximize the window or drag it around. It's grey now with (Adwaita).

I can't tell which css file to edit or which field to change in gnome tweak tool.

Ideally I could just add a few overrides to the .gtkrc-2.0 or .gtkrc-3.0 file, because ultimately it's just gVim, Firefox and the Gnome Terminal that I'd like to change that titlebar color on.

Any help would rock!

Here's my .gtkrc-2.0

```
style "vimfix" {
  bg[NORMAL] = "#000000" # this matches my vim theme 'Normal' bg color.
}
widget "vim-main-window.*GtkForm" style "vimfix"
```

So far this just fixes a tiny grey bottom-border on gVim. But it's not changing the color on the titlebar of the window of gVim.

**Update:**
Tried making this change in ~/.themes/Adwaita-borderless/metacity-1/metacity-theme-3.xml, and selecting 'Adwaita-bordeless' for the window theme in the gnome-tweak-tool, but it didn't seem to effect anything:

```
<draw_ops name="titlebar_fill_focused">
  <gradient type="vertical" x="0" y="0" width="width" height="height">
    <color value="#000000" />
    <color value="#000000" />
  </gradient>
</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="titlebar_fill_unfocused">
  <rectangle color="C_titlebar_unfocused" x="0" y="0" width="width" height="height" filled="true" />
  <rectangle color="#000000" x="0" y="0" width="width" height="height" filled="true" />
</draw_ops>
```

Comment: I read somewhere that firefox and vim get their styling from gtk2.0, so that's why I was trying to go the gtkrc2.0 route. Any ideas would be really helpful : )

Answer (score 4):

You can edit title bar colours here:

> sudo gedit /usr/share/themes/Adwaita/metacity-1/metacity-theme-3.xml

Edit these two sections:

> name="titlebar_fill_focused"
>
> name="titlebar_fill_unfocused"

It will change colours of all windows (checked in fedora)

Comment: Hmmm, I tried that with no luck : ( I updated my questions with what changed I made to my code. I'm new to theming, I don't have to restart my computer, or make changes in Gnome Tweak Tool for changes to take effect, do I? I have my GTK and window theme set to Adwaita.

Comment: You need to restart gnome shell. Press Alt+F2, type r and hit Enter.

Comment: Okay, restarts just fine, but I see no changes to my theme.

Comment: Hmmm... okay, I managed to crash my system, deja-dup restore didn't work, but after messing around for a while everything seems to be back in order except for my system default font. My gnome-terminal font is weird, and so is gvim's. Not my day.

Comment: Coming back around to this. Any ideas? I still have the same issue.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I am using the Crux theme, and simply can-t read the text with the focused window. I've seen a `colorize="gtk:bg[SELECTED]"` field, but don't exactly know how to change the color in question, namely the font color. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.